# Getting [nil, nil] in multicolumn index in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this:

```
class CreateStudentHasSubjects < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]                                                                                                            
  def change                                                                                                                                                             
    create_table :student_has_subjects do |t|                                                                                                                            
      t.references :student, null: false, foreign_key: true                                                                                                              
      t.references :subject, null: false, foreign_key: true                                                                                                              
      t.boolean :is_active, null: false, default: true                                                                                                                   

      t.index [:student, :subject] #Here's where the question comes in.                                                                                                                                       

      t.timestamps                                                                                                                                                       
    end                                                                                                                                                                  
  end                                                                                                                                                                    
end
```

and when I execute `$ rails db:migrate` I get, in the `schema.rb` file:

```
create_table "student_has_subjects", force: :cascade do |t|                                                                                                            
    t.integer "student_id", null: false                                                                                                                                  
    t.integer "subject_id", null: false                                                                                                                                  
    t.boolean "is_active", default: true, null: false                                                                                                                    
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false                                                                                                                                 
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false                                                                                                                                 
    t.index ["student_id"], name: "index_student_has_subjects_on_student_id"                                                                                             
    t.index ["subject_id"], name: "index_student_has_subjects_on_subject_id"                                                                                             
    t.index [nil, nil], name: "index_student_has_subjects_on_student_and_subject" #WTF? [nil, nil]                                                                                        
  end
```

That `[nil, nil]` kind of scares me. Can anyone explain me why do I get that instead of:

```
t.index ["student_id", "subject_id"], name: "index_student_has_subjects_on_student_and_subject"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you use the reference names instead of the column names. According to the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord%2Flib%2Factive_record%2Fconnection_adapters%2Fabstract%2Fschema_definitions.rb#L169), `t.index` only supports columns names.

Also note that if you add a multi-column index on `student_id` and `subject_id`, the first index on `student_id` is probably redundant. That's the case for PostgreSQL at least.

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove this...

```
t.index [:student, :subject]
```

and add this...

```
class CreateStudentHasSubjects < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]                                                                                                            
  def change                                                                                                                                                             
    create_table :student_has_subjects do |t|                                                                                                                            
      t.references :student, null: false, foreign_key: true                                                                                                              
      t.references :subject, null: false, foreign_key: true                                                                                                              
      t.boolean :is_active, null: false, default: true                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

      t.timestamps                                                                                                                                                       
    end  

    add_index :student_has_subjects, [:student, :subject]                                                                                                                                                 
  end                                                                                                                                                                    
end
```

Comment: `t.index` inside of the `create_table` block is acceptable: https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Table.html#method-i-index

Comment: @coreyward, that's true. Either way I get the same weird result.